# Pass a value from one child component to other component - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Iam trying to get a value from one child component to another. I have a thought process, But being a intermediate I cant implement it.

**Thought is like:** When a dropdown component of (say A.js) is selected by user then its effect should be visible in (say B.js).
Iam aware of React-Redux's callback function and gone through the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), but cant implement it in my code.

Here is my code with relevant information, please help to get the desired output.
PS: Pardon the indentation.

**A.js**

```
class sidebar extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: 'None' 
            }
        };
    }

...
...

OnChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.currentTarget.value })
      };


render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <select 
                 onChange={(event) => this.OnChange(event)}
                  className="form-control">
                    <option>Please select a role</option>
                    <option value ="a">a</option>
                    <option value ="b">b</option>
                    <option value ="c">c</option>                            
                </select>
                <p>role select is: {this.state.value}</p>

            </div>)
}
```

**B.js**

```
class projectStatus extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       ...
       ...
    };
  }

  render() {
    const receiveValue = (value) => {console.log("value received from A",value)}
    return(
        <LoadingOverlay
        receiveValue={receiveValue}>
        <p>{this.state.receiveValue} </p>
        </LoadingOverlay>
    )}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a concept of react that is called [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), which consists of moving the state/props for the parent components so it can be shared between it's child components by passing it down as props.

Explaining it better, you should move the `value` state and the OnChange function to the parent component in common, and will pass it as props to component A and B so both of them could use the same value.

Another way, is to write the component as functional components and use the [ContextAPI](http://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to share state globally in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont want to use redux you can [lift your state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). So the idea is define your particular property in the Lowest common ancestor.

Suppose, this is your heirarchy:
D -> X - > C -> A

F -> X -> E-> B

So in this case you would want the property to reside with X. You define a function in X  and as a prop to the children components (A & B) from level X. Then trigger the particular function in the child when you are making the change. You can imagine all the calls going up to X, and their you can change the particular prop which you are passing to C and E, which are inturn passing it to A and B respectively.